# Theano compilation hangs due to reg query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" /v "10.0" fail

Tags: visual-studio, python-2.7, registry, windows-7-x64, theano

I try to run Python 2.7.11 (Anaconda 2.4.1) code which utilizes Theano 0.8.0 computations. Simple GPU test from Theano documentations passes but my code fails.
After a lot of compilation it hangs on

```
reg  query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" /v "10.0"
```

according to Process explorer. If try to execute in command line:

```
C:\scisoft>reg  query "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7" /v "10.0"
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

How this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

It seems manual adding registry entry

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7
    10.0    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\
```

solved this problem.

UPDATE:
Another time there was missing:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7
    10.0    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\
```